# How can you make an MFC application with an HTML view consistently accept drag-dropped files?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to decipher CHtmlView's behaviour when files are dragged into the client area, so I've created a new MFC app and commented out the CHtmlView line that navigates to MSDN on startup.  In my main frame, I've overridden CWnd::OnDropFiles() with a function that shows a message box, to see when WM_DROPFILES is sent.

OnDropFiles() gets triggered on all except the first time you try to drag a file into the application.  Uniquely, that first time appears to be interpreted by the application as a request to display the data in the file rather than a request to open the file.  I've tried overriding OnDrop() from the view class, but it's never called.

Why is the first time different?  How can I catch all attempts to drag a file into my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the underlying `WebBrowser` control behaviour. `CHtmlView` sets `RegisterAsDropTarget` to `true` by default, which means the control intercepts the drop operation and performs its own processing.

If you want to inhibit it, call `SetRegisterAsDropTarget(FALSE)` in your `OnInitialUpdate` implementation. All drop operations will then interact with the main window.

Answer (score 0):

Preface: I'm extrapolating from documentation I've found, and am not concerned if I'm wrong. Please make sure the following explanation makes sense, ie try it, before voting-up my answer or accepting it :)

After Googling `OnDropFiles`, I discovered that it's inherited from the `CWnd` class: [(MSDN page)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62zys01d(VS.80).aspx)

---

According to that MSDN article:

**Parameters**
`hDropInfo`

> A pointer to an internal data structure that describes the dropped files. This handle is used by the `DragFinish`, `DragQueryFile`, and `DragQueryPoint` Windows functions to retrieve information about the dropped files.

Quoting later:

> "The framework calls this member function when the user releases the left mouse button over a window that has registered itself as the recipient of dropped files.
>
> "Typically, a derived class will be designed to support dropped files and it will register itself during window construction.
>
> This member function is called by the framework to allow your application to handle a Windows message. The parameters passed to your function reflect the parameters received by the framework when the message was received. If you call the base-class implementation of this function, that implementation will use the parameters originally passed with the message and not the parameters you supply to the function."

---

That *appears* to indicate that until the function has been registered, it won't work 'as expected'.

Therefore, I believe that what's happening is that the first time you drop something onto the CHTMLView, it registers itself, and only ***then*** 'works as expected'.

If my understanding is correct, then a new question is raised, which is how can you force the registration of the View. From the related links on the MSDN Technote, it looks like you can force `DragAcceptFiles` [(see here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776406(VS.85).aspx) to run, which would otherwise be triggered when the drop event finished.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, but I think that's not it.  DragAcceptFiles() is called from the boilerplate code generated for the app class's InitInstance() function.  InitInstance() runs when the program launches, and has certainly finished before I start dragging and dropping things.

Comment: ok - well, that's what it looked like. Sorry it wasn't right.

Answer (score -1):

What I would recommend is to switch to [HTMLayout](http://www.terrainformatica.com/htmlayout/main.whtm) -- it's waaaay better than CHtmlView.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already found a workaround that would be less hassle than incorporating third-party code: navigate to a blank page on startup.  What I'm after is an answer to the question about CHtmlView.